# Node js: get all values of key in array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I have data that looks like this (sanitized). This is axios output from Azure artefact feeds into response array

```js
{
  "value": [
    {
      "normalizedName": "@test",
      "name": "@test",
      "versions": [
        {
          "normalizedVersion": "1.2.6",
          "version": "1.2.6",
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "normalizedName": "@test2",
      "name": "@test2",
      "versions": [
        {
          "normalizedVersion": "4.0.1",
          "version": "4.0.1",
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "normalizedName": "@test3",
      "name": "@test3",
      "versions": [
        {
          "normalizedVersion": "2.2.0",
          "version": "2.2.0",
        }
      ],
    },
  ]
}
```

and I need to get both the `normalizedName` and `normalizedVersion` of every item

eg

```
[ '@test','1.2.6' ]
[ '@test2','4.0.1' ]
[ '@test3','2.2.0' ]
```

and so on

I have tried this but cant understand how to get from item 0 to item 1 and so on.
I'm not sure if I need to create a loop counter and put them all into a loop, but seems messy.

```js
for (var key in response.data.value[0]) {

  if (key === 'normalizedName') {
    // console.log(response.data.value[0][key]);
    verList.push(response.data.value[0][key]);
  }

}
for (var key in response.data.value[0].versions[0]) {

  if (key === 'normalizedVersion') {
    // console.log(response.data.value[0].versions[0][key]);

    verList.push(response.data.value[0].versions[0][key]);
  }
}
```

My output is this:

```js
[ '@test', '1.2.6' ]
```

I've tried other things that get the same result, but just cant get it to go through the full JSON object/body and pull out all the versions.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: `for..in` is not how you iterate an array in js, you need `for..of`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `reduce` and `map` to get the needed result:

```js
const res = {
  "value": [
    {
      "normalizedName": "@test",
      "name": "@test",
      "versions": [
        {
          "normalizedVersion": "1.2.6",
          "version": "1.2.6",
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "normalizedName": "@test2",
      "name": "@test2",
      "versions": [
        {
          "normalizedVersion": "4.0.1",
          "version": "4.0.1",
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "normalizedName": "@test3",
      "name": "@test3",
      "versions": [
        {
          "normalizedVersion": "2.2.0",
          "version": "2.2.0",
        }
      ],
    },
  ]
}

console.log('res', res.value.reduce((acc, next) => { acc.push(...next.versions.map(v => [next.normalizedName, v.normalizedVersion])); return acc }, []))
```

Comment: `reduce` is not needed here

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for thank you. It's very similar to @Raghavan Vidhyasagar's answer, but crucially iterates over if there are multiple versions in each normalizedName.
I don't have enough reputation to mark this as the answer sorry.

Comment: @Anatoly, how would I then traverse the array to find the versions that equal eg 2.2.5?

Comment: @gog please show your version of code without `reduce`

Comment: `how would I then traverse the array to find the versions that equal eg 2.2.5` - that's another question. Please don't try to solve several questions in one post and comments.

Comment: @Anatoly:  e.g. `value.flatMap(x=>x.versions.map(y=>[x.name, y.version]))`

Comment: @gog yeah, I forgot about `flatMap`, usually I use a similar method from lodash, that's why I showed the example with `reduce` (not to use an external dependency).

Answer (score 1):

This JavaScript code defines an object `res` with a property named "value," which is an array of objects. Each object in the array represents a package with properties such as "normalizedName," "name," and "versions." The "versions" property is an array containing an object with version information.

The code then uses `console.log` to output an array of arrays. Each inner array contains the package name `(value.name)` and the corresponding version `(value.versions[0].version)` extracted from each object in the "value" array. This is achieved using the map function to iterate over the array and create a new array with the specified values for each package.

```js
const res = {
  "value": [
    {
      "normalizedName": "@test",
      "name": "@test",
      "versions": [
        {
          "normalizedVersion": "1.2.6",
          "version": "1.2.6",
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "normalizedName": "@test2",
      "name": "@test2",
      "versions": [
        {
          "normalizedVersion": "4.0.1",
          "version": "4.0.1",
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "normalizedName": "@test3",
      "name": "@test3",
      "versions": [
        {
          "normalizedVersion": "2.2.0",
          "version": "2.2.0",
        }
      ],
    },
  ]
}

console.log(res.value.map(value => [value.name, value.versions[0].version]))
```

Comment: plus 1 for the correct answer, minus 1 for the lack of any explanations.

Comment: Its simple iteration, so though he/she will understand it just by looking it. My bad edited the answer with explanation.

Comment: This was helpful thank you. It didn't get me exactly what I was after (perhaps my question could've been more exact) as it only returns the first normalizedVersion, but in my data there could be many.